# I developed website for movies and pushed it to Heroku successfully(done with node js and React) but it's not running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Here is the `package.json` for the root `react` app

```js
    {
      "name": "movie-timeline",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
        "create-react-app": "^3.4.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.2",
        "react-spring": "^8.0.27"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",
        "start": "serve -s build",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "proxy": "http://localhost:3006",
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ...
        ],
        "development": [
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
```

I added `set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"` script so it can run locally and on `Heroku`.

This is what `heroku` logs:

```sh
$ heroku logs --tail

Warning: heroku update available from 7.38.2 to 7.42.6.
2020-08-12T22:32:51.450396+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-08-12T22:32:51.452680+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! movie-timeline@0.1.0 start: `serve -s build`    
2020-08-12T22:32:51.452896+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-08-12T22:32:51.453058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-08-12T22:32:51.453205+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the movie-timeline@0.1.0 start script.
2020-08-12T22:32:51.453348+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-12T22:32:51.467442+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-12T22:32:51.467627+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-12T22:32:51.467740+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-12T22_32_51_460Z-debug.log
2020-08-12T22:32:51.556136+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-12T22:32:51.706650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed   
2020-08-13T00:12:06.031766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting   
2020-08-13T00:12:29.908831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256591+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256605+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie-timeline@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256606+00:00 app[web.1]: > serve -s build
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256606+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T00:12:34.267835+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: serve: not found
2020-08-13T00:12:34.277638+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-13T00:12:34.277976+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-08-13T00:12:34.278160+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-08-13T00:12:34.278407+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
// ...
```

can someone help me, please?

Comment: Hi, are you able to add the **code snippets** that `heroku` displays while running after the `react` app is built?

Comment: you can visit http://amazz-movie-timeline.herokuapp.com/ to check what is displays, bear in mind that it runs locally with no problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the link. I expected to find what i've seen given that `heroku` process wasn't successful. So what we're interested in to look at the logs from `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: thanks, I have executed that command but it's showing a long message. so I updated the question with a part of it. tell me if you need more please since I'm new and I can't post images

Comment: Thanks, it's missing critical information. If you're on github, the easiest way to share that log is by creating a [gist file](https://gist.github.com/), just dump the entire log there and share a link to that file here. Once we review the log file, we'll pinpoint the crucial things.

Comment: done,so i should paste this to show you? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMazaal/5258447ca9febd6bee23feea73dceae4/raw/b3a2bc0841a8684030da00719fdc5698f440dcb2/the%20result%20of%20heroku%20logs%20--tail

Comment: Will take a look at the detailed log file, thanks.

Comment: `heroku` is running your `start` script but you don't have the `serve` package installed locally within your project. Please install it locally (I assume you already have it globally on your local machine). Do you have a `Procfile`..?

Comment: Problem solved! thanks a lot, it was the serve package as u said. I installed it locally and the website is working perfectly online. How can I mark that this question is solved by you?

Comment: I have added the answer, let me update your question to reflect where actual problem was.

Comment: To "mark question as solved", you click the "upper" arrow next to the answer (below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are pushing to `Heroku`, it run this script from your `package.json` within the `react` app:

```js
{
  "scripts": {    
    "start": "serve -s build",
    // other
  },
}
```

And this is confirmed from the `heroku` logs...

```sh
// ...
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256605+00:00 app[web.1]: > movie-timeline@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256606+00:00 app[web.1]: > serve -s build
2020-08-13T00:12:34.256606+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-13T00:12:34.267835+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: serve: not found
// ...
```

Because you installed `serve` globally on your local machine, the project runs.
Therefore you need to install `serve` locally for `heroku` to run it while starting your app.

```sh
$ npm install --save-dev serve
```

That way, `heroku` will be able to run your `"start"` script.